# Bit-banging I2C question

Tags: i2c, bit-bang

When bit-banging I2C using 2 PIO lines do these lines still need to be pulled high? Obviously using a dedicated I2C bus the lines must be pulled high as the pins are open-drain outputs but PIO pins aren't open-drain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both lines need to be pulled high at all time.

Also, when bitbanging I2C, rather than switching the LOW/HIGH states of the pin, switch between LOW/HiZ by simply altering the DDR/DIR registers.

Comment: The data pin needs to be pulled high, but not necessarily the clock.

Comment: Why is that? Well, I guess, if you only have one master, don't account for slave-induced clock stretching, etc.

Comment: Why switching between LOW/HiZ is rather than switching between LOW/HIGH states of the pin?

Comment: As this isn't an answer, it should probably be posed as its own question, or a comment on Dzarda's answer. But anyway, High-Z is used because I2C is a multi-device bus and is designed so that devices are only allowed to drive low, and then an external resistor pulls the line high - this means if one device is trying to output a 1 while another is driving a 0, then they don't short each other out - because the device trying to output a 1 is in High-Z and a resistor is pulling up for it.

Comment: @TomCarpenter: For the case of a single master driving SPI devices that do not use clock stretching, using an actively driven clock is fine, provided that the time required for the passive pull-up on SDA to generate a rising edge is shorter than the minimum delay between releasing SDA and driving SCK high.